# How to join two sql squery results

Tags: sql

I have these two queries:

```
select house_id
from prices
group by house_id;

select location from houses;
```

I want replace house_id from prices with location from houses. How can I do this? They've both got same No of tuples.

```
houses(id, country, location)
pirces(house_id, realtor)
```

I want to get:

```
prices(location)
```

Comment: please post the definition of your tables and exactly what you want to get. Saying that you want to replace the house_id from prices with location from houses you mean that it should be the result of the query you are trying to build. Right?

Comment: As @ChristosPaisios said. But assuming what I assume it would be something like SELECT location FROM houses AS HOU INNER JOIN prices AS PRI ON PRI.house_id=HOU.house_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your table definitions first it would be something similar to:

```
SELECT P.house_id, H.location 
FROM prices AS P
JOIN houses AS H on H.ID = P.house_id
GROUP BY P.house_id, H.location
```

Comment: Thanks it works! but you get the error: " Unknown column 'h.ID' in 'on clause'" if the h is lowercase, it should be uppercase

Comment: I thought SQL wasn't case sensitive?

Comment: @Bobby For statements like the above, MSSQL is not case sensitive and MySQL `is` case sensitive.